# Access computed property in ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

With this controller:

```
CMS.PeopleController = Em.ArrayController.extend
    orderedNames: ( ->
        // Some ordering here...
    ).property "content.names"
```

...nothing appears here:

```
{{#each controllers.people.orderedNames}}
    <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

I guess that's because some binding to `content`, but I have no idea how to get it working... Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @each to refer to properties on individual items in an array [as a dependent key]: `content.@each.name` Also, ensure your property is `return`ing a value.

Comment: Thanks, how can I return `hasMany`? `return @get("content.@each.articles")` doesn't work...

Comment: @kraftwer1 use the `mapProperty` of `Ember.Array`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_mapProperty